# How can print node value XML in an orderly way PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a XML like this:

```
<description>
    <heading id="01"> Math </heading>
    <p id="01"> Text 1 </p>
    <heading id="02"> History </heading>
    <p id="02"> Text 2</p>
    <p id="03"> Text 3</p>
    <heading id="03"> Biology </heading>
    <p id="04"> Text 4 </p>
</description>
```

I also have many xml files have structure like this one, they are only different from amount of `<p>` node of every `<heading>` node.
How can I print `<heading>` and some `<p>` node and the second heading....

I tried to use foreach, but it's not true.
my code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("NWB2.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo "<b>".$xml->{'description'}->{'heading'}."</b>";
echo "<p>".$xml->{'description'}->{'p'}."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: If your XML is as you say at the top, you don't need to have the root element (`description`) when accessing the data, so `$xml->{'description'}->{'p'}` could be written as `$xml->p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a case of having different style depending on the input tag, you can use a `foreach()` loop and output the value according to the tag type...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("NWB2.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ( $xml as $type => $value )    {
    if ($type == "p")  {
        echo $value;
    }
    else {
        echo "<b>$value</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, my purpose is I want the <heading> to be bold style and <p> to be in normal style while print into html

Comment: I've updated the answer, it simply echos out p tags and puts headers into bold.

Comment: Does it work only with foreach? How can I use it without foreach?

Comment: As far as I know, there would need to be some sort of loop in there (even if you used an `array_...()` method it's still a loop).